# Problem connecting to azure gitlab vm instance after changing external url

Tags: azure, gitlab, virtual-machine

I am trying to create a self-managed version of gitlab that runs on azure using this link: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/azure/
It all works fine until I get to the "Change the GitLab external URL" section. I follow the instructions exactly: I replace the external url and I comment out the lines and I run the reconfigure command. But this breaks connections to the vm. I can no longer connect to it at all (previously I could connect, but I would always be redirected to the public unsecure url as the article says).
Now I simply get a "this site can't be reached error" [public ip] refused to connect.
Any ideas what step I'm missing.

I also think the article is slightly outdated because of the section that tells us to rename the utility bitnami uses:
"sudo mv /opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/bnconfig /opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/bnconfig.bak"
There is no longer a bnconfig file that exists in the gitlab azure instance.

I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Are you using standard ports for HTTP/HTTPS or alternative ports? It would be helpful if you could provide the diff between your working configuration and the non-working configuration after your `external_url` change.

Comment: Are you running the reconfigure command after editing GitLab's config? (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/restart_gitlab.html#omnibus-gitlab-reconfigure)

Comment: Yes I am. It doesn't work still

Answer (score 0):

I just had the exact same problem. What worked for me was to edit the config by:

```bash
sudo vim /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
```

And then enable letsencrypt by changing this line to `true`:

```
letsencrypt['enable'] = true
```

Save, and then do the usual

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

According to [the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/azure/index.html#change-the-gitlab-external-url) it is supposed to be enabled automatically:

> Using https in the URL automatically enables, Let’s Encrypt, and sets HTTPS by default

...but that statement no longer holds, it seems.

Also, I did not figure out the missing `/opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/bnconfig` file that should be renamed (it is also missing for me), but I don't seem to loose the config after restarting the VM, so this part of the docs just seem outdated.